# Estimating $\sum_{p^k \leq x, k \geq 2} \log p$

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to estimate $\sum_{p^k \leq x, k \geq 2} \log p$ where $x$ is a positive number, $k$ is a natural number bigger than $1$ and $p$ is a prime. Could it be true that $\sum_{p^k \leq x, k \geq 2} \log p \ll \sqrt x$?. I think I can use the information that the number of primes up to $\sqrt x$ is approximately $ \frac{\sqrt x}{ \log \sqrt x}$ and maximum value of $\log p$ is $\log \sqrt x$. But I could not proceed since the value of $k$ for each prime also matters. I appreciate any help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function#Asymptotics_and_bounds Your function is $\psi(x)-\vartheta(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{p^k\le x,k\ge 2} \log p & = \sum_{p\le \sqrt{x}}\sum_{k\le \log_p x}\log p\\
&=\sum_{p\le \sqrt{x}}\log p\, \lfloor\log_p x\rfloor\\
&\le \sum_{p\le \sqrt{x}}\log p\, \log_p x\\
&=\sum_{p\le\sqrt{x}}\log x = \log x\ \pi(\sqrt{x})\\
&\ll \log x\ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log\sqrt{x}} = 2\sqrt{x} \ll \sqrt x.
\end{align}

Comment: How is $2\sqrt x \ll \sqrt x$?

Comment: @BenjaminWang The usual definition of $\ll$ in Analytic Number Theory is: $f(x) \ll g(x)$ if $f(x) \le C g(x)$ for some constant $C$. In this case you may take $C=1/2$.